# Переключение на следующую форму с помощью кнопки

Tags: javascript, html

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <form id="form1" method="POST">
        <input value="form 1" />
    </form>

    <form id="form3" method="POST" style="display:none">
       <input value="form 2" />
    </form>

    <form id="form3" method="POST" style="display:none">
        <input value="form 3" />
    </form>
  
    <button class="btn btn-info" id="next">Next</button>
</div>
```

Как переключить на следующую форму при нажатии кнопки 'Next'?

Comment: нет, допустим первая будет видна, все следующие class="hidden". Сейчас переделаю :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Самый простой вариант: хранить номер (`index`) отображаемой формы и при нажатии кнопки показывать следующую (`index + 1`):

```js
$(function() {
    var $forms = $('#wrapper form');
    var index = $forms.filter(':visible').index();
    $('#next').on("click", function() {
        $forms.eq(index).hide();
        index = (index + 1) % $forms.length;
        $forms.eq(index).show();
    });
});
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <form id="form1" method="POST">
        <input value="form 1" />
    </form>
    <form id="form3" method="POST" style="display:none">
        <input value="form 2" />
    </form>
    <form id="form3" method="POST" style="display:none">
        <input value="form 3" />
    </form>
    <button class="btn btn-info" id="next">Next</button>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Плюс-минус то же самое без использования *jQuery*:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    var $forms = document.querySelectorAll('#wrapper form');
    var index = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < $forms.length; i++) {
        var style = window.getComputedStyle($forms[i]);
        if (style.display != "none") {
            index = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    var $next = document.getElementById('next');
    $next.addEventListener("click", function() {
        $forms[index].style.display = "none";
        index = (index + 1) % $forms.length;
        $forms[index].style.display = "block";
    });
});
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <form id="form1" method="POST" style="display:none">
        <input value="form 1" />
    </form>
    <form id="form3" method="POST">
        <input value="form 2" />
    </form>
    <form id="form3" method="POST" style="display:none">
        <input value="form 3" />
    </form>
    <button class="btn btn-info" id="next">Next</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо!  будет репутация 15 - поставлю вверх :)

Comment: @Niflungar на здоровье. 15 репутации устроить - дело не сложное :) Добавил в ответ пример без использования jQuery. Выглядит топорно, но всё же и в вопросе не было метки _jquery_, и не все его используют по тем или иным причинам.

Comment: а вот и 15 :)) заслуженный "вверх"

Answer (score 1):

Еще вариант с `jQuery`

```
$('#next').click(function(){
    $('#wrapper form:visible').hide().next().show();
})
```