# Переключение на следующий блок по клику на кнопку

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как с помощью *jQuery* навесить на кнопку переход на следующий блок?

```js
$(function() {
    var $forms = $('#wrapper .qiuz');
    var index = $forms.filter(':visible').index();
    $('#next').on("click", function() {
        $forms.eq(index).hide();
        index = (index + 1) % $forms.length;
        $forms.eq(index).show();
    });
});
```

```html
<form method="POST">
    <div class="qiuz-wrapper" id="wrapper">
        <div class="qiuz">
            <label class="btn btn-default">
                <input type="radio" name="radio1" value="radio"> 1
            </label>
            <label class="btn btn-default">
                <input type="radio" name="radio1" value="radio"> 2
            </label>
            <label class="btn btn-default">
                <input type="radio" name="radio1" value="radio"> 3
            </label>
            <label class="btn btn-default">
                <input type="radio" name="radio1" value="radio"> 4
            </label>
            <label class="btn btn-default">
                <input type="radio" name="radio1" value="radio"> 5
            </label>
            <hr>
        </div>
        <div class="qiuz" style="display:none">
            <label class="btn btn-default">
                <input type="radio" name="radio2" value="radio"> 1
            </label>
            <label class="btn btn-default">
                <input type="radio" name="radio2" value="radio"> 2
            </label>
            <label class="btn btn-default">
                <input type="radio" name="radio2" value="radio"> 3
            </label>
            <label class="btn btn-default">
                <input type="radio" name="radio2" value="radio"> 4
            </label>
            <label class="btn btn-default">
                <input type="radio" name="radio2" value="radio"> 5
            </label>
            <hr>
        </div>
        <div class="qiuz" style="display:none">
            <label class="btn btn-default">
                <input type="radio" name="radio3" value="radio"> 1
            </label>
            <label class="btn btn-default">
                <input type="radio" name="radio3" value="radio"> 2
            </label>
            <label class="btn btn-default">
                <input type="radio" name="radio3" value="radio"> 3
            </label>
            <label class="btn btn-default">
                <input type="radio" name="radio3" value="radio"> 4
            </label>
            <label class="btn btn-default">
                <input type="radio" name="radio3" value="radio"> 5
            </label>
            <hr>
        </div>
        <button id="next">Следующий</button>
    </div> <!--/.qiuz-wrapper-->
</form>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: а вот [этот вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/469479/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%8E%D1%89%D1%83%D1%8E-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%83-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B8) не тоже самое?

Comment: тот же, только я не могу понять как тот код применить к этому шаблону, почему-то у меня не получается.

Comment: а вот это, после первого вопроса, `</div><hr>` ошибка? в других после последнего `label` вставляется

Comment: и еще вопрос: когда доходит до последнего вопроса и жмете _next_ что должно происходить?

Comment: да, исправил...

Comment: у меня три блока, 2 с которых скрыты, хочу чтобы при нажатии кнопки next, скрывался блок 1 и открывался блок 2.

Comment: @Niflungar, если вы на третьем блоке жмете кнопку - что должно происходить? Например: ничего, перейти на первый вопрос, вернуться на вопрос назад, еще что-то?

Comment: ну по плану, это блоки с тестом, на последнем блоке должен быть submit и отправка результатов.

Comment: @Regent, при смене селектора ничего не выходит - вот http://jsfiddle.net/niflungar/ex8tbqg6/

Comment: @Niflungar, потому что дефолтное type для  button - _submit_. Сделайте его _type="button"_ и все должно заработать

Comment: @Niflungar вообще говоря, выходит. Просто у вас все три формы абсолютно одинаково выглядят. Я только `return false` добавил, чтобы форма не отправлялась, так как кнопка находится внутри формы: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ex8tbqg6/5/). И, конечно, сделал разные значения в формах, чтобы было видно.

Comment: @Regent, благодарю, разобрался теперь :)

Comment: @Niflungar на здоровье. Если вы пишете какой-то опрос или викторину, то имеет смысл изменить везде `qiuz` на `quiz`. А с вопросом надо что-то делать: либо удалить его, либо оформить ответ, который будет принят и который полностью описывает решение проблемы.

Comment: @Regent, в принципе это ж дубликат

Comment: @Grundy не совсем: там кода не было вовсе, а тут проблемы были с `<button>` внутри формы и с тем, что блоки в форме выглядели абсолютно одинаково.

Comment: @Regent, ну теперь - да. Кстати, в том вопросе это работало, похоже потому, что button - не внутри форм был

Comment: @Grundy, скорее всего так и есть, спасибо что растолковали:)

Comment: @Grundy, кстати, а что если вместо `style="display:none"` применить class bootstrap `hidden`?

Comment: @Niflungar, вообще говоря без разницы, если не ошибаюсь у него внутри тот же `display:none` и прописан. Тут лучше написать стиль для контейнера: типа если класс вложен в него = то `display:none` и сделать класс который наоборот будет показывать жлемент

Comment: @Grundy, ок, посмотрю. еще вопрос если можно.. а как сделать, чтобы на последней блоке, кнопка не перебрасывала на 1 блок?

Comment: проверить что мы на последнем блоке - и не переходить на следующий :-)

Comment: @Grundy, извини, что может напрягаю.. а на примере можно ?

Comment: всего три формы, _index_ может принимать значения: 0,1,2 - если Index==2 - то на последней форме - и делаем что-то другое

Comment: @Grundy, понял, спасибо еще раз :)

Comment: @Grundy да, там кнопка была вне формы, поэтому `.preventDefault()` (а точнее - как обычно `return false`) я там не писал.

Answer (score 2):

Вариант с `jQuery`

```
$('#next').click(function(){
    $('.qiuz:visible').hide().next().show();
});
```